# Redirecionar site com .htacess

Tags: htaccess, redirecionamento, mod-rewrite, redirecionamento-de-url

Preciso usar urls amigáveis e estou tentando fazer um ajuste com o .htacess

Tenho uma url:

```
http://www.site.com.br/default.asp?id=meuid&acao=minhaacao&hint=minhahint
```

Preciso que ela fique assim:

```
http://www.site.com.br/meuid?acao=minhaacao&hint=minhahint
```

Tentei fazer da forma abaixo sem êxito:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ default.asp?site=$1&pid=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

E assim

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /default.asp?id=$1&acao=$3&hint=$4  [QSA]
```

Comment: E qual erro que está acontecendo?

Comment: Apresenta o erro padrao :Erro HTTP 403.14 - Forbidden
O servidor Web está configurado para não listar o conteúdo deste diretório.