# Substituir caracteres de uma URL via .Htaccess

Tags: htaccess, redirecionamento, redirecionamento-de-url

Tenho o seguinte modelo de URLs:

```
http://dominio.com.br/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?Palavra
http://dominio.com.br/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?Outra_Palavra
```

e preciso redirecionar para este novo modelo:

```
http://dominio.com.br/#Palavra
http://dominio.com.br/#Outra_Palavra
```

Quero substituir o trecho `cgi-bin/wiki.pl?Palavra` por `#Palavra` ao redirecionar.

Meu .htaccess está assim atualmente:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dominio.com.br
RewriteRule ^ http://www.dominio.com.br%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/wiki.pl?(.*)$ /#$1 [R=301,NC,L,NE]
</IfModule>
```

Usando este modelo de .htaccess atual, está redirecionando de:
`http://dominio.com.br/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?Palavra` para: `http://dominio.com.br/#?Palavra`

Notem que a interrogação ainda está presente na URL após o redirecionamento, porém preciso que fique assim:
`http://dominio.com.br/#Palavra`

Obs.: Parece que quem criou a primeira estrutura de URLs (que no caso não fui eu) usou a "Chave" do Query String como sendo um valor, e por este motivo não estou conseguindo resgatar a Chave para usar na nova estrutura de URLs.
Se a URL fosse `http://dominio.com.br/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?chave=Palavra` ficaria mais fácil resolver, porém da forma como está atualmente não estou conseguindo resolver.

Alguém sabe como resolver isso ?

Comment: E quais são os caracteres a serem substituídos justificando o título da sua pergunta? Se a intenção é deixar a URL mais amigável,  esse redirecionamento não seria ao contrário, da segunda URL para a primeira?

Comment: Já deu uma pesquisada no site? Tipo nessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60936/5878).

Comment: Pesquisei sim, porém até agora não encontrei nada que me ajudasse à resolver meu problema. Editei a pergunta acrescentando maiores detalhes para um melhor entendimento do problema.

Answer (score -2):

Achei a solução. Segue `.htaccess` atualizado:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dominio.com.br
RewriteRule ^ http://www.dominio.com.br%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^cgi\-bin/wiki\.pl$ /\#%{QUERY_STRING} [QSD,R=301,L,NE]
</IfModule>
```